# IBM Watson Assistant: Condition for checking if input date is greater or less than 18 years old

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

This is what happens:

The user is asked to enter their date of birth, identified with the variable [ $ date_bird ] to be extracted from the dialog with [ input.text ].

I need to verify that the date entered by the user is not greater or less than 18 years old.

Comment: Hello, @Alfred Koen, welcome to SO. Can you provide the code you have tried to achieve this, so we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the IBM Watson Assistant supported [expressions for date and time calculations](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-date-time-calculations).

Take the date of birth, add 18 years and check if it is before or after now.

You can use expressions in a condition on a node. However, I would probably evaluate the condition separately and set up a new context variable that indicates true / false on the "is over 18".

In the following example I have used this expression to decide on the age:

```
@sys-date.plusYears(18)<= today()
```

My test intent responds with **old enough** or **too young**, depending on the birthdate.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read the guide you refer to. However, the assistant is asked to verify the 18-year factor as a condition for proceeding further and only after having detected a minor age with respect to the aforementioned must he notify the user. I can not create the condition also because of the input variable that I have set up. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can apply those mentioned functions in the condition.

Comment: I do not understand.
The @ sys-date <today (). MinusYears (18) condition function returns only the date 18 years ago. When I use it as a condition it doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't understand the syntax as explained in the page where you directed me.
Thank a lot !

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't understand the grammar of the syntax

Comment: Of course.
Can the same check be done to check the minimum length of a number or the data of a variable?

Comment: Why not? You can perform any checks

Comment: Can I use this condition with a variable that I created?
Specifically, how can I indicate that the variable value [text and/or numbers ] with max of 15 characters for the user input?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been trying to set the condition in order to verify the user input of characters, with max of 15 characters between text and/or numbers, but it dosen't work.
I've made a variable [ $codice_fiscale ] but I can't aplly the condition. 
Can you please help me in order to make it work?

Comment: This seems like a new question. Please open a new question, so that it can be easily found by others.

Comment: I have insert new answer [ Watson Assistan - @sys-date with condition ]. Please